# Is tip a derogatory word

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I have noticed the word tip being used for waiters. Is the word tip applied to people of small income groups? Does it have any negative to it, or can one use this word for anyone and say like - I will tip you.

Comment: What kind of people? What kind of situation?

Comment: Tip isn't applied to *people* at all. It's an object [or an action]. It doesn't in any way describe the person to whom it is given.

Answer (score 1):

"**Tip**" is, whatever else, informal speech. So it is not so much the type of people with whom one uses "tip", but the level of formality with which one is speaking. For example I might "tip" the waiter in a restaurant, but if I was claiming the bill on my expenses I might write the amount in a column headed "gratuities" - if there was one.

Comment: In the 1960s people travelling to the Soviet Union were given, on arrival, a leaflet of advice about social customs that might be different from those in the traveller's home country. It said that on no account should waiters, taxi drivers, hotel porters, etc be offered tips, as this would insult their socialist ideals and make them angry. Travellers who forgot to follow this guidance found that the oversight was very readily forgiven.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - In the 80's travelling behind the 'iron curtain' as was, taking a good supply of pound or dollar notes was a really good way to get great service :)) It seemed at the time, these socialist ideals were very flexible when faced with hard currency… as local currency couldn't buy appliances or white goods.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey In Japan the advice to tourists is usually never to give tips. It is true that Japanese people can feel patronised and demeaned by being offered a tip - especially by a person of western appearance.  (Same can apply to middle-class Chinese in SE Asia) However it can be the method of giving which particularly offends - and they feel more comfortable if you put the money in an envelope and hand it to them while politely bowing. The Chinese use little red packets, called *Ang Pows* especially for the purpose - some banks hand them out as freebies. But the Chinese don't bow.